# Wagtail/Django: Query filter to return only the pages the user has acess/permissions?

Tags: python, django, wagtail

I'm going through the documentation at: http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.7.1/reference/pages/queryset_reference.html.

Is there a filter to return only the pages the user has access to? I can only see `public()` and `not_public()`.

I have some pages which privacy is set to Private (accessible to users in specific groups). And would like to exclude them from the query results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such filter in PageQuerySet.  You can however create your own QuerySet that adds an authorized filter and use that.  The following code comes from the Joyous events `EventQuerySet` and is based upon `PageQuerySet.public_q` and `BaseViewRestriction.accept_request`.  It gets all the restrictions that could apply, excludes the ones that the user passes, and then filters out the pages with the remaining restrictions.

```
from wagtail.core.query import PageQuerySet
from wagtail.core.models import Page, PageManager, PageViewRestriction

class MyQuerySet(PageQuerySet):
    def authorized_q(self, request):
        PASSWORD = PageViewRestriction.PASSWORD
        LOGIN    = PageViewRestriction.LOGIN
        GROUPS   = PageViewRestriction.GROUPS
        KEY      = PageViewRestriction.passed_view_restrictions_session_key

        restrictions = PageViewRestriction.objects.all()
        passed = request.session.get(KEY, [])
        if passed:
            restrictions = restrictions.exclude(id__in=passed,
                                                restriction_type=PASSWORD)
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            restrictions = restrictions.exclude(restriction_type=LOGIN)
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            restrictions = restrictions.exclude(restriction_type=GROUPS)
        else:
            membership = request.user.groups.all()
            if membership:
                restrictions = restrictions.exclude(groups__in=membership,
                                                    restriction_type=GROUPS)
        q = models.Q()
        for restriction in restrictions:
            q &= ~self.descendant_of_q(restriction.page, inclusive=True)
        return q

    def authorized(self, request):
        self.request = request
        if request is None:
            return self
        else:
            return self.filter(self.authorized_q(request))
```

You could then set this to be your model's default QuerySet.

```
class MyPage(Page):
    objects = PageManager.from_queryset(MyQuerySet)()
```

Then when filtering your MyPage objects you can say `MyPage.objects.live().authorized(request).all()`

Hope that is helpful.  May contain bugs.